# ColdFusion include

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I'm currently learning ColdFusion. I have a background in PHP and I am a bit confused by this.

I have a select menu and I want the options to be saved in a different file. (For example options.cfm) When I call the file I want to include the options inside the select menu.
Now I realize I could probably do it with something like this:

```
<select>
    <cfinclude template="options.cfm">
</select>
```

Although what I really want to do is a bit more complicated. I want to have the `cfinclude` saved inside a variable. I realize this won't work but it is basically what I want to accomplish:

```
<cfset options=<cfinclude template="options.cfm">>
```

Is there anyway to do that? Or at least a better way to accomplish what I am doing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [cfsavecontent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d57.html) tag, It allows you to capture what would otherwise have been output to the response :

```
<cfsavecontent variable="options">
    <cfinclude template="options.cfm">
</cfsavecontent>
```

UPDATE: Instead of using cfsavecontent every time you need those options saved to a variable, you could instead do it once inside of the options.cfm file. Then, anytime you include the file, it will create the variable.

```
<!--- Inside options.cfm --->
<cfsavecontent variable="options">
    <option value="val1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="val2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="val3">Value 3</option>
</cfsavecontent>
```

Then where ever you needed that variable to exist you would simply need to cfinclude that file.

```
<cfinclude template="options.cfm">
```

Answer (score 0):

i know this is a bit late but one issue i see is if this is site wide or just per client.

if site wide then great but if it is different on each client it could cause some issues.

my solution as i don't use cookies or sessions is to create a temp table and write the variables to it. each page that loads and needs that data queries and/or writes to the table.
a client id variable is created when the client visits the site and the table is named it.

just a thought.